# Parametric programming in C language

Tags: c, dynamic

I have some programs that are identical for different entities. They do exactly the same thing but with different structures. Each entity has its own program in a C language file and I would like to write a single program for all the entities, but it should change the behavior according to the entity.

Currently I use for example the printf function for cities like this:

```
printf ("%i %s %c %llu %lu", city.city, city.name, city.cityType, city.population, city.country);
```

And for the country like this:

```
  printf ("%i %s", country.code, country.name);
```

I also use `fwrite(&city,sizeof(strctreCity),1,RBin)`; and `fwrite(&country,sizeof(strctreCountry),1,RBin);` which I would like to change dynamically according to the parameter received by the program and the information in the structure file of each entity. The definition of structures is found in a file for each entity like this:

The city.str file of the city entity contains

```
unsigned long city;
char name[9];
char cityType;
unsigned long long population;
unsigned long country;
```

The country entity file country.str contains

```
 unsigned long country;
 char name[9];
```

I would like that when invoking the program adding a parameter and that the program changes its behavior according to the parameter and the str file that corresponds to the parameter. Without hard codding the program.

```
./sampleEntity city
```

either

```
./sampleEntity country
```

The question is not how to read the structure file or how to manage the parameters of the programs, rather the question is, how can I dynamically manage a program that changes according to the structure of an entity.

Comment: Please edit the question title, and make it in English.

Comment: You're misusing ["dynamic programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). :)

Comment: @ Kaz. Wow, yes, you are rigth, thanks.  Any sugetions? I would fix it.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It vaguely has to do with parsing and templates, but it is actually unclear what you are trying to do or what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: user19117857, Why does code use `"%i"` with `unsigned long city`?

Answer (score 0):

**Part A (derived from comments)** 
With respect to: "how can I dynamically manage a program that changes according to the structure of an entity." Answer: Identify the structure of entity, e.g. either by keyword in a line or by number of words in a line. Then invoke the subroutine for the corresponding entity. Further details of this can be found in the comments.

**Part B (first answer)**
Following code evaluates the arguments of calling an executable.
I suppose, it is straightforward, how it works.
`get_arguments` provides different return codes for the different cases

```
./sampleEntity city
```

or

```
./sampleEntity country
```

(You can use any return codes. This is just an example.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_arguments(int argc, char** argv){
    
    if(argc!=2) return 3; // return error code: wrong number of arguments
    if(strcmp("city",argv[1])==0) return 1;
    if(strcmp("country",argv[1])==0) return 2;
    return 4; // return error code: no match with available keywords
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    int res;
    
    res = get_arguments(argc, argv);
    printf("case = %i\n",res);
    
    // if(1==res) main_routine_city();
    // if(2==res) main_routine:country();
}
```

Instead of writing "magic numbers" in the source code. It is usually a good idea to use constants (preprocessor directives), like

```
#define _RETCODE_CITY 1
#define _RETCODE_COUNTRY 2
```

and so on. But that is further fine tuning and just an option.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question.  Dbase II used “&” and I think they called it a macro, which replaces the “on the fly” code with the &variable content. Other programs that work with SQL use the PREPARE statement, which is used by writing the content of the SQL that you want into a variable, then preparing the variable and finally executing it with the EXECUTE statement.

In my particular case,  I want is to write, for example, printf(XXXX) where XXX is the result of having read the *.str files.

Comment: Ok, you would like to execute the command which you have written into a variable, right? Then, have a look to C commands: `sprintf(...)`and `system(...)`

Comment: Keep it simple!

Comment: I am really grateful for your collaboration. What I really want is to be able to have text files with the description of the fields of any entity and use them to update data, add, modify, select and delete. I think that the only thing I should have, as data for my program, are the data structures which are already stored in the city.str and country.str files mentioned above.

Comment: Read in the data of your *.str-file(s) and then process the data (insert, copy, add, remove ...)?! Read the file into a buffer, get the number of lines, split each lines into strings, process the strings, ... Is that what you need?

Comment: Read in the data of your *.str and then process the data (insert, copy, add, remove ...)?! Yes.  You are rigth!   read is no problem for me.  The problem is how to use diferent structures in a printf or fwrite.   with only one program and no "cases" or "if"

Comment: Ok, one simple idea is to have one keyword in the beginning of each line in the str-file, like `CITY`, `COUNTRY`, `DISTRICT`, or whatever. Check for this keyword and then process the line according to the keyword. This system can be extended to further keywords. Otherwise you need check for the number of "words" in a line. In your case above, 2 words means Country, 5 words means City ...

Comment: I suppose my last comment is the answer to your question. If yes, please let me know. Then I would update my answer to include this "Line Identification" either e.g. by keyword or by number of "words" in a line.

Comment: Then, please accept answer - which I updated.